# How can I change the background color of my TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net

So basically whenever you make a new TabControl it's all white, but when you change the color of the inside tab I can't change the color of the TabControl itself? Here is what I mean

[image: 1]

The inside is black as I want, but the outside is white and can't change it?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Unless you takeover to draw the control and the tab pages yourself. Google for examples.

Comment: When we change the color of the inside tab we can't change the color of the TabControl itself. But we can draw our own control to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't directly change the color directly through the attribute.

But we can modify the color in other ways.

We can achieve the modification effect by filling the rectangular area with color.

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle
```

**Complete code:**

Add this in the load event：

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.tabControl1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    this.tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(this.tabControl1_DrawItem);
}
```

Drawing function：

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
    //Get the working area of the TabControl main control
    Rectangle rec = tabControl1.ClientRectangle;
    //Create a StringFormat object to set the layout of the label text
    StringFormat StrFormat = new StringFormat();
    StrFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;// Set the text to be centered vertically
    StrFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;// Set the text to be centered horizontally

    // The background fill color of the label, it can also be a picture (e.Graphics.DrawImage)
    SolidBrush backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
    SolidBrush fontColor;// Label font color
                         //Draw the background of the main control
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColor, rec);

    //Draw label style
    Font fntTab = e.Font;
    Brush bshBack = new SolidBrush(Color.DeepPink);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabPages.Count; i++) {
        bool bSelected = (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == i);
        Rectangle recBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(i);
        RectangleF tabTextArea = (RectangleF)tabControl1.GetTabRect(i);
        if (bSelected) {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bshBack, recBounds);
            fontColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[i].Text, fntTab, fontColor, tabTextArea, StrFormat);
        } else {
            fontColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[i].Text, fntTab, fontColor, tabTextArea, StrFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

**If you have questions about my code, please add a comment below.**

Comment: If you have questions, please let me know.

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: yes it does help me